# ImportError: cannot import name 'CLOSED' from 'websockets.connection'

Tags: python, websocket, rasa

I installed rasa on a virtual environment on windows. But while I am trying to check either rasa is installed or not, it is showing an error that says-

`ImportError: cannot import name 'CLOSED' from 'websockets.connection'`

I have reinstalled rasa, and installed websockets. But still getting the error.

Python version is 3.10.2

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Currently, it's best to install Rasa with Python ver. 3.8 or 3.9.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try installing websockets version 10.0 like this:
`pip install websockets==10.0`
It should help (it helped me)